# How can I fix this code set up to check which numbers are prime numbers?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement, modulo

Here is the code:

```
def checkIfPrime (numberToCheck):
    for x in range(2, numberToCheck):
        if (numberToCheck%x == 0):
            return False
    return True
```

It works almost perfectly. The problem I see is that if I check whether zero is a prime number, it says "True." Like this:

```
>>> checkIfPrime(0)
True
```

But zero is not a prime number, obviously! What can I do to the code so it will return "False" when I check to see if 0 is a prime number?

---

EDIT: I see the problem now with my original code. But someone asked me to update my question to show how I attempted, and failed, to check my parameter checkIfPrime to make it so the program would return 'False' when I checked if the number zero is prime. So here's that attempt:

```
def checkIfPrime (numberToCheck):
    for x in range(2, numberToCheck):
        if (numberToCheck%x == 0):
            return False
        if numberToCheck == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Check what you get from calling range(2, 0)

Answer (score 2):

Just check it first (and also check for non-integers and 1 at the same time...):

```
from numbers import Integral
def checkIfPrime (numberToCheck):
    if not isinstance(numberToCheck, Integral):
        return False
    if numberToCheck < 2:
        return False
    for x in range(2, numberToCheck):
        if (numberToCheck%x == 0):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: OK. I was trying to do what you did, but I put the if numberToCheck == 0 indented and under the for x in range.... line.

Why doesn't it work to put numberToCheck == 0 under the for x in range... line?

Comment: But you didn't have the `if numberToCheck == 0:` check first. If you don't have that, then `range(2, numberToCheck)` is going to be an empty range and so you'll fall through to return True.

Comment: Note: `1 is not a prime`

Comment: Updated answer to check 0 and 1 and also non-integers.

Comment: There is no point in checking up to ```numberToCheck```. Only checking up to the square root of that (included) is sufficient and much more efficient.

Comment: @ThomasErnste can you update your question to show where exactly you put the check when it wasn't working? It's hard to tell just by describing it.

Comment: @daphtdazz I added the code for how I attempted to make numberToCheck return as False for the value zero. As you can see, I put it under the for loop.  I see that I need to enter this line first, before the for loop, although I don't really understand why I can't put this line where I put it. Apparently the program is just ignoring this line when it's inside the for loop.

Comment: That's because when numberToCheck is 0, `range(2, numberToCheck)` is `[]` (an empty list) and so there is nothing to iterate over and the code just drops through to the final `return True`

Comment: @daphtdazz One last thing: why is this line necessary:  if not isinstance(numberToCheck, Integral):  ???  It seems to me like the code works without this line.

Comment: You're right, it should do, it's just an easy check to make first that would speed things up if you were likely to be passed a lot of floating point numbers.